# Should I include function names into log files?

Tags: logging, obfuscation

Our application uses intensive logging into XML file to make it easier for developers to deal with a problem when it comes to technical support. Usually a log entry is created when application enters some function and upon exiting it. The question I ask myself is: is it appropriate to include function names to log entries, e.g. should we log

`Entering DoSomeStuff()`

`...`

`Leaving DoSomeStuff`

or

`Doing some stuff`

`...`

`Finished doing some stuff`

?

Will logs with function names compromise our obfuscation?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, a log is the antithesis of obfuscation -- it outlines in DETAIL the internal operation of your application.  If you want to obfuscate your app's logic, then a log is the worst kind of thing you can put in a place where a user can access.  At least encrypt it with a key that is heavily obfuscated in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no putting actual method names into the logging is a bad idea, perhaps you could work around this by putting more ambigious messages such as a "Generating Website", but then again this depreciates the idea of doing the logging in the first place.

Personally, I'd use a third party tool such as RedGate Smart Assembly, which would automatically create log reports of client crashes/errors.  Thus providing technical support with a solid foundation of what the problem is.

[Redgate Smart Assembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/)